# Polymer and Angular: fail in trying to pass data from controller to the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, data-binding, polymer

My problem is the next:

1. I have AngularJS app using custom Polymer elements inside it;
2. I have a controller called, for example, **Main**. It handles **/main** route and uses its own view - **main.html**;
3. There is **my-element** inside the main.html;
4. I initialize a collection in my controller and pass it to the element using **document.querySelector('my-element').collection = $scope.collection**. It works when I open /main URL directly and page is loaded. But it doesn't work when I directly open another route and then go to the /main - because controller runs **after** ready() and create() methods of my-element work.

I have a bad solution with setInterval() inside the my-element create() method. 
Please, help the beginner.

Thanks in advance!

```js
// my controller
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, collection) {
  
  $scope.collection = collection; // resolved from the route
  
});


// my element ready() method
...
ready() {
  
  
  // without timeout it will throw an exception, because JSON.parse parses {{list}} string itself on route state change.
  setTimeout(function() {
    
    this.list = JSON.parse(this.getAttribute('list'));
      
  }, 300);
  
}
```

```html
<!-- MyController view -->
<my-element list={{collection}}></my-element>
```

Comment: Can u show us some code?

Comment: [Mohhamad Walid](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2407522/mohammad-walid), you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Polymer data binding as following:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="listJson">
  <template>
    ....
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      created: function() {
        this.list = [];
      },
      ready: function() {
        this.initList();
      },
      listJsonChanged: function() {
        this.initList();
      },
      initList: function() {
        this.list = JSON.parse(this.listStr);
      }
    })
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Then in the view:

```
<my-element listJson="{{collection}}"></my-element>
```

Comment: It doesn't work too - JSON.parse throws error, because it parses {{collection}} string, not the collection JSON itself yet. I found another solutions: 1) **domReady** event handler for the attributes parsing; 2) **$watch**ing document.querySelector('my-element').initList for the assigning the list data inside an AngularJS controller. Its _undefined_ at the beginning of controller loading.